# What is correct way to secure vertx web applications?

Tags: security, web, service, router, vert.x

Vertx 4 comes with the nice feature to secure services using ServiceAuthInterceptor. But to use this feature we need to provide auth-token. Do we need to create proxy
in each time router callback is invoked?

```java
router.get("/some").handler(this::handleSomething);

....

private void handleSomething(RoutingContext ctx) {
        final String authToken = getTokenFromUser(ctx.user());
        final DeliveryOptions options = new DeliveryOptions()
                .addHeader("auth-token", authToken);
        final SomeService someService = SomeService.createProxy(
                ctx.vertx(),
                "someaddress",
                options);
        
        someService.getSomething(ar -> {});
}
```

Is that a righ approuch? Or are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading the articles under `authentication and authorization` in the official docs: https://vertx.io/docs/#authentication-and-authorization

All of the options there a viable, they can also be used as a base for custom logic.

For example in my projects I use JWT tokens and something like the following (example is in kotlin but can be written in java as well):

```kotlin
class HttpServerVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {
  override suspend fun start() {
    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    val jwtAuth = initJwtAuth()
    router.route().handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuth))
    // add other routes that should be protected
    ...
  }

  private suspend fun initJwtAuth(): JWTAuth {
    // init JWTAuth with jwks retrieved from my auth server's /.well-known/jwks.json endpoint
  }
}
```

With the same concept you can replace `route().handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuth))` with the way you want to protect your routes. You can also put more handlers to do some more authorization logic - i add other handlers before specific routes to achieve RBAC like behavior for specific endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the question is how to secure services (not routes). Example, I have service which gives different information depending on user rights (user may not access all the database information). So I have to options: send user information in service request parameters or using auth-token to services. Using auth-token is good for me. But to do this we need to add special header to message going to the event bus. Please see source of https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-service-proxy/blob/4.0.0/src/main/java/io/vertx/serviceproxy/ServiceAuthInterceptor.java

Comment: That depends how you access those services. you can add the logic with utilities per service, you can add interceptors on the event bus if each service is a verticle with a consumer to the event-bus etc. There is no "right way" here - it depends

Comment: On the service side I prefer interceptor. The what is better way to pass specific header (auth-token) from router context (which contains user information) to service proxy. Is it ok to create service proxy at each call of router hanler as I described in the question?  Because you specify delivery options with headers once at the time of service proxy creation. So to add specific header I need to create new proxy each time. Is it right?

Comment: Got to say i do not use the service proxy and wire the event bus calls myself, so i can not answer that.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Personally I use because it is better for the refactoring purpose. IDE could rename methods easily and 'action' header is regenerated automatically while building